# combine multiple select statement in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've just started learning SQL. Here is part of my Database:

[image]

I want to get the project name from the Project table with condition:

`name = 'turbine'` and `value = '03'` in `Parameter` table.

I have wrote the following query and it seems to work!
But I was wondering if any smarter query can do the job for me :

```
SELECT name
FROM Project
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT projectId
    FROM Cases
    WHERE id IN (
        SELECT caseId
        FROM ParamValue
        WHERE parameterId IN (SELECT id FROM Parameter WHERE name = 'turbine')
          AND value = '03')
    )
;
```

Comment: You can use [`JOIN()`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/)

Comment: It's better to join the tables than to do a bunch of subqueries like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of several nested  IN clause with subquery seems more easy to read a proper set of inner join

```
select distinct Project.name 
from Project 
INNER JOIN  Cases ON Cases.projectId = Project.id
INNER JOIN ParamValue ON ParamValue.caseId = Cases.id
  AND ParamValue.value ='03'
INNER JOIN Parameter ON ParamValue.parameterId = Parameter.id 
  AND Parameter.name =  'turbine'
```

Comment: I'm getting the error : `Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
Ambiguous column name 'name'`

Comment: @user9112767 Did you try changing `name` to `Project.name` (or replace `Project.` with the table where `name` comes from).

Comment: @WernerHenze, Yes, I have put the `Project. ` before the `name`, but the result here is 114 rows and my select statement returns the 11 rows !

Comment: @user9112767  answer  updated .. with proper table name and distinct  for avoid duplication

Comment: @scaisEdge, I realized when I use the select statement with `where` if I have duplicated `id` like (10 times 2)  It will just returns one project name, but in the join statement It will repeat the project name 10 times ! how could I fix that to get unique results ?

Comment: @user9112767  the distinct clause should avoid rows  duplications ...

Answer (score 1):

Sure here you go without subqueries:

```
SELECT pj.Name
FROM Parameter p
INNER JOIN ParamValue pv ON pv.Value = '03' AND p.Id = pv.parameterId
INNER JOIN Cases c ON pv.caseId = c.Id
INNER JOIN Project pj ON c.projectId = pj.Id
WHERE p.name = 'turbine'
;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select pr.name from Project pr 
left join Cases c on pr.name = c.id
left join ParamValue pv on c.id = pv.parameterId
left join Parameter p on  p.id = pv.parameterId
where p.name = 'turbine' and pv.value = '03';
```

Comment: @WernerHenze, the same error with your query : `Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
Ambiguous column name 'name'`

Comment: @user9112767 Not my query. I was just editing the question and fixed a type (Projetc -> Project). The answer is from Noureddine.